# Why are map tiles being repeated? Using MapServer and Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, coordinate-system, mapserver, mapfile

Problem I have: map tiles from my layer are being repeated.

Shapefile is projection 3059.
I have specified 3059 is in the mapfile and also when creating map object.

I know OpenLayers.Layer.WMS is recommended, but when I use it I only see empty map. When I use OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer, map is displayed (and tiles are repeated), so I'm using that for now.

**My layer (EPSG:3059) looks like this**

[image: My layer]

Versions:
Openlayers 2.13.1
MapServer 6.0.3

**WMS Server mapfile:**

```
MAP
    NAME country_map
    STATUS ON
    SIZE 800 500
    EXTENT 313187.4 146161.56 766469.92 470367.64
    UNITS METERS
    SHAPEPATH "shapefiles"
    IMAGECOLOR 155 155 155

    WEB
        TEMPLATE "template.html"
        IMAGEPATH "C:/MS4W/ms4w/apache/htdocs/gis/output/"
        IMAGEURL "/gis/output/"

        METADATA
            "wms_title"             "MapServer + Openlayers"
            "wms_onlineresource"    "http://localhost:1025/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\MS4W\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\gis\mapfile2.map"
            "wms_enable_request"    "*"
            "wms_srs"               "EPSG:3059"
        END
    END

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:3059"
    END

# example layer
    LAYER
    METADATA
        "wms_title"             "lat_rob_region"
    END
    NAME "lat_rob_region"
    DATA lat_rob_region
    STATUS ON
    TYPE POLYGON
        CLASS
            NAME "lat_rob_region"
            STYLE
                COLOR 0 255 0
            END
        END
    END
END
```

**Javascript:**

```
var lon = 25;
var lat = 57;
var zoom = 5;
var map, layer1;

function init()
{
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map',{displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3059")} );

    layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Country map", 
            "http://localhost:1025/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/MS4W/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/gis/mapfile2.map", {layers: 'lat_rob_region'},
            {gutter: 15},{srs: 'EPSG:3059'});
    map.addLayer(layer1);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
    map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
}
```

Comment: Ok. I have realized that I can't reproject from 4326 to 3059 in a simple way. Server is rendering image tiles, I think I'd have to use Proj4js for reprojection. So the only problem I will work on now is the tile being repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reference to this problem here: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/layers.html.

*If you are using a Layer.MapServer, and your map is being repeated several times, this indicates that you have not properly configured your map to be in a different projection. OpenLayers can not read this information from your mapfile, and it must be configured explicitly. The FAQ on [setting different projection properties](https://web.archive.org/web/20091121215435/http://faq.openlayers.org/map/how-do-i-set-a-different-projection-on-my-map/) provides information on how to configure different projections in OpenLayers.*

---

Link was dead but I managed to find an up to date version via [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). It says:

*OpenLayers supports any projection. A projection is a way of converting geographic coordinates -- latitude and longitude -- into a plane. There are three parameters in OpenLayers which are important to set if you wish to change projections: **maxExtent , maxResolution, projection.***
*These parameters are set, respectively, by default to:

-180,-90,180,90

1.40625

EPSG:4326*

***maxExtent*** is the maximum bounds, in the units of your map, of the plane in which you want to display information.
 **maxResolution** is the number of mapunits per pixel at the highest zoom level
 **projection** is used when issuing WMS or WFS requests to inform the server of the projection desired.*

*To calculate maxResolution, it is generally safe to take the maximum dimension of the maxExtent, and divide that value by the width of your map div. So, for a map from -180 to 180, take the width (360) divided by a default map size of 256 to get 1.40625. To automate this process, you can also use 'auto' for a maxResolution.

You should also change the '**units**' property on your map: this property is what allows OpenLayers to know what scale things are being rendered at, which is important for scale-based methods of zooming and the Scale display control.*

---

**Solution:**

**Bounds** match EXTENT from my mapfile.
**maxResolution** is set to '0.125' or 'auto', both work. I got 0.125 this way:
(57-25) / 256 =
32 / 256 =
0.125
(57 is latitude and 25 is longtitude for country of Latvia)
**Projection** EPSG:3059 matches my mapfile.

Changing my map initialization to this fixed the tile repetition problem:

```
new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(313187.4, 146161.56, 766469.92, 470367.64),
maxResolution: 'auto',
units: 'meters',
projection: "EPSG:3059"});
```