# How to specify the lat/long and bounding box of MapServer WMS layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, extents

I am using MapServer to add a WMS layer on a basemap using OpenLayers 3. The WMS generates a png image from a shapefile, which I need to overlay on a basemap. Below is the code which I used to overlay the WMS layer.

```
var zone_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("FEMA Flood Zones",
"http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/MapServer/maps/femawms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=FEMA_NFHL_POLY_STATUS&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-69730.2,777408,331075,959674&FORMAT=image/png", {
  layers: "Flood_Hazard_Zones",
  transparent: "true",
  format: "image/png"
});

map.addLayer(zone_wms);
```

However, when I do that, the layer is repeated on each of the tile on the basemap. For example, when I am at a zoom level=1, there are 8 images (one of each tile) displayed. When I am at zoom level=2, there are 32 images displayed on the basemap... and so on. Also, I am not sure how to specify the exact location (lat+long+bounding box) of the WMS layer that is overlaid on the map.

I am sure, you would have figured it out that I am newbie to the GIS world..so please forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: The addition of `SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=FEMA_NFHL_POLY_STATUS&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-69730.2,777408,331075,959674&FORMAT=image/png` as your end point in the code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been [answered before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93879/why-are-map-tiles-being-repeated-using-mapserver-and-openlayers), this individual had a similar problem. Best of luck.